# JQuery IP Info - If condition when get request exceeds maximum allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using IPInfo.io to track the visitor's country.
It allows me to do a maximum of 1000 requests per day (for free).

I want it to check if the country is 'BR'. 
If it is, "do something".
If it isn't or if the maximum number of daily requests has been exceeded, "do something else".

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
   var pais = (response.country);

   if(pais=='BR'){
    //do something//        
   } else {
   // do something else
   };
}, "jsonp");
```

Now, the `else` clause doesn't work here when the requested queries to IpInfo have been exceeded.

In that case, I get the error: `429 (Too Many Requests)`

I've tried:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  var pais = (response.country);
    if(pais=='BR'){
    //do something //
    };
}, "jsonp")
    .fail(function(){
    //do something else//
});
```

But the result is the same.

How do I solve this?

Note: It isn't my idea to break the TOS of this service, but to perform a default action when my daily limit has been reached.

Comment: _429 (Too Many Requests)_ says it all, you've exceeded your daily number of requests. I have tried your function and it works as expected

Comment: Exactly, and do I express what to do when that happens?

Comment: Seems like jquery does not support this HTTP Status or it might be a bug. http://jsfiddle.net/c158wa6u/

Comment: .fail doesn't work for crossdomain jsonp requests. neither does the error: callback. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: There really is  no good solution to this. Your only options are either to consume this service using your webserver, or to use a setTimeout that gets cleared on success. If it never clears, assume it was in error.

Comment: @KevinB thanks, I just looked at the $.get documentation, thought it could be a solution

Comment: If you used your webserver to consume it, you could cache the results to make those 1000 requests last a little longer, assuming you aren't breaking any ToS agreements.

Comment: @KevinB the first idea (setTimout) looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the full jQuery.ajax() call in the manner below...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ipinfo.io/json",
    success: function(response) {
        var pais = (response.country);
        if(pais=='BR') {
            //do something //
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    statusCode: {
        429: function() {
            alert( "Number of tries exceeded" );
        }
    }
});
```

This will give you the ability to check the HTTP status codes. You can extend it to check for more than just the "429" code you mentioned if desired.

Comment: Is it even possible to retrieve the statuscode of a script loaded using a script tag with just js?

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error (429) and the function with the alert isn't triggered

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were using JSONP. Edited my answer to fix your problem. The API docs for ipinfo.io show how to use strait JSON requests and by doing so you remove the limitations of JSONP.